# Operand Type Clash - SQL Server INSERT stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I understand the error, I am simply not sure why this is occurring. I have written a simple insert procedure to update a list of users.

Error:

> Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Procedure addNewUser, Line 0 [Batch Start Line 2]
>   Operand type clash: int is incompatible with date

Procedure declaration:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[addNewUser] 
    @fName VARCHAR(255), 
    @lname VARCHAR(255), 
    @dob DATE, 
    @email VARCHAR(255), 
    @gender VARCHAR(255), 
    @level VARCHAR(255) AS

INSERT INTO [dbo].[User] ([firstname], [lastname], [dob], [email], [gender], [accesslevel]) 
VALUES ('@fName ', N'@lname', @dob, N'@email', N'@gender', N'@level')
```

Calling procedure:

```
DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[addNewUser]
        @fName = N'Ste',
        @lname = N'King',
        @dob = 19780103,
        @email = N'Books@email.com',
        @gender = N'Male',
        @level = N'Free'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
GO
```

Comment: well….@dob is being passed as an `int`, use single quotes: `@dob = '19780103'`

Comment: I have tried this, however, I am now being informed this is incorrect syntax at the first quotation mark. 

EXEC @return_value = [dbo].[addNewUser]
  @fName = N'`Ste`',
  @lname = N'`King`',
  @dob =   IncorrectSyntax->`19780201`,
  @email = N'`email@books.com`',
  @gender = N'`male`',
  @level = N'`free`'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First your procedure is wrong. You shouldn't put your variables into the single quote for your purpose:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[addNewUser] 
@fName  varchar(255), 
@lname  varchar(255), 
@dob    DATE, 
@email  varchar(255), 
@gender varchar(255), 
@level  varchar(255) 
AS

INSERT [dbo].[User] 
    (
      [firstname]
    , [lastname]
    , [dob]
    , [email]
    , [gender]
    , [accesslevel]
    ) 
VALUES 
    ( 
      @fName 
    , @lname
    , @dob
    , @email
    , @gender
    , @level
    )
GO
```

Also you send int value to the date field. You need yo put into the single quote:

```
DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[addNewUser]
        @fName  = N'Ste',
        @lname  = N'King',
        @dob    = '19780103',
        @email  = N'Books@email.com',
        @gender = N'Male',
        @level  = N'Free'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
```

Comment: Thank you, I think I have copy pasted something without truely trying to understand. This is a clear example! Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Just put `@dob = 19780103` into quotes `'1978-01-03'`:

```
USE [t7068097]
GO

DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[addNewUser]
        @fName = N'Ste',
        @lname = N'King',
        @dob = '1978-01-03',
        @email = N'Books@email.com',
        @gender = N'Male',
        @level = N'Free'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

**UPDATE:**

```
SELECT CAST('1978-1-1' AS DATE)
SELECT CAST('19780101' AS DATE)
```

Comment: like to enforce pushing dates in '1978-01-03' or  '1978/01/03'

Comment: I have tried this, I thought would work but I am receiving the same error.

Comment: @SimonDean try to use ANSI standard `1978-01-03`

Comment: @SimonDean And what's the datatype of the `dob` column in the `User` table?

Comment: Its Date type pal.

Comment: @SimonDean please, see `UPDATE` section.

Comment: and this is nested before the return value is selected I presume?

Comment: @SimonDean no, I just showed that it works. Your error was that you are put parameters into single quotes.

Comment: Thank you for your help.